# Create a program in Java that allows the user to play the Rock-Paper-Scissors game against the computer

Tags: java, static, boolean

"Create a program in Java that allows the user to play the Rock-Paper-Scissors game against the computer". I'm new to Java, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as after it prompts the user to enter a response, nothing happens. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

```
     public class RockPaperScissors
         {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
           {   
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("(R)ock, (P)aper, (S)cissors, or quit");
        String playersChoice = scan.nextLine(); 
    }
    String playersChoice = " " ,computerChoice;

    int wins = 0; 
    int losses = 0;
    int ties = 0; 

    while(!playersChoice.equals ("quit"))
    {
        if (playersChoice.equals("R") ||
        playersChoice.equals("P") ||
        playersChoice.equals("S"))

        {
            computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

            if (playersChoice.equals(computerChoice))
            {
                System.out.println("Tie");
                ties++;
            } 
            else {

                boolean result = playerWins(playersChoice, computerChoice);
                if (result == true)
                {
                    wins++;
                    System.out.println("Your Point!");          
                    System.out.println(playersChoice + " beats " + 
                        computerChoice); 
                }
                else 
                {
                    losses++; 
                    System.out.println("My Point!");  
                    System.out.println(computerChoice + " beats " + 
                        playersChoice); 
                }
            }



            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            System.out.println();   
        }
    }

    System.out.println("You won " + wins + " times.");
    System.out.println("You lost " + losses + " times." );
    System.out.println("We tied " + ties + " times." );      
}

public static String getComputerChoice() 
{
    int randomInt;

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);

    if (randomInt == 0) 
    {
        return "R";
    } 
    else if (randomInt == 1) 
    {
        return "P";
    } 
    else 
    {
        return "S";
    }
}

public static boolean playerWins(String playersChoice, 
String computerChoice)
{   
    boolean playerWins = false;

    if ((playersChoice.equals("R") && computerChoice.equals("S")) ||
    (playersChoice.equals("P") && computerChoice.equals("R")) ||
    (playersChoice.equals("S") && computerChoice.equals("P")) ) 
    {
        playerWins = true;
    }
    else 

        playerWins = false;

    return playerWins; 
}
```

}

Comment: You're defining playersChoice twice - once in an inner block. The original value is therefore ignored. I'm also assuming the huge block of code at the start is your main method, as it has no header. (If it isn't, you've just accidentally put all this code in an initializer block, which is probably not what you want.)

Comment: your code looks incomplete, can you please give us the full code ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're putting the section that gets input from the user in its own block.  But since you're doing that, you have to declare `playersChoice` before the block starts so that it will be accessible after the block ends.  What you're currently doing is redeclaring `playersChoice` after the block ends, and that's a completely new variable, unrelated to the variable that you stored the user input in, which has now gone out of scope and is inaccessible.

Comment: i added the header! sorry about that

Comment: so where should I move the public static boolean playerWins(String playersChoice, 
    String computerChoice)" section to? if i move it to before the section that gets user input, it says "illegal start of expression"

Answer (score 1):

I would store your choices in collections that allow for very quick look up without a lot of work. This also limits the amount of conditions in your if statements.

```
    Hashtable<Integer, String> compChoices = new Hashtable<>();
    HashSet<String> choices = new HashSet<>();
    choices.add("R"); compChoices.put(0, "R");
    choices.add("P"); compChoices.put(1, "P");
    choices.add("S"); compChoices.put(2, "S");
    int wins = 0; 
    int losses = 0;
    int ties = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("(R)ock, (P)aper, (S)cissors, or quit");
    String userInput = "";

    do {
        userInput = scan.nextLine();
        if(choices.contains(userInput))
        {
            String compChoice = compChoices.get(new Random().nextInt(3));
            if(compChoice.equals(userInput))
            {
                System.out.println("You Tied!");
                ties++;
            }
            else if(playerWins(userInput, compChoice))
            {
                System.out.println("You Win!");
                wins++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Computer Wins!");
                loses++;
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid input");

    } while (!userInput.equals("quit"));

    System.out.println("You won " + wins + " times.");
    System.out.println("You lost " + losses + " times." );
    System.out.println("We tied " + ties + " times." );
```